# Enable Development time IIS support from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core, iis, visual-studio-2019

I like to keep a PowerShell script that installs and configures my development applications (Visual Studio, VSC, Git etc etc) and environment, mainly using chocolatey. This helps if I change machine or we take on a new developer.

Here is part of my existing script. It installs Visual Studio 2019 and required workloads then enables the local IIS Windows Features for local debugging:

```
choco install -y visualstudio2019professional
choco install -y visualstudio2019-workload-netweb
choco install -y visualstudio2019-workload-data
choco install -y visualstudio2019-workload-manageddesktop
choco install -y netfx-4.5.2-devpack

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -All -FeatureName IIS-WebServerRole
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -All -FeatureName IIS-BasicAuthentication
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -All -FeatureName IIS-WindowsAuthentication
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -All -FeatureName IIS-ASP
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -All -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET45
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -All -FeatureName IIS-HttpRedirect
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -All -FeatureName WCF-HTTP-Activation
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -All -FeatureName WCF-HTTP-Activation45
```

I have recently come across the requirement to enable "Development time IIS support" in the Visual Studio Installer for .NET Core applications as per https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/development-time-iis-support-for-asp-net-core-applications/#development-time-iis-support. Is there a way I can do this from PowerShell?

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/jberezanski/ChocolateyPackages/issues is a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out...

```
choco install -y visualstudio2019-workload-netweb --package-parameters "--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.IISDevelopment"
```

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-professional?view=vs-2019&preserve-view=true#aspnet-and-web-development